# Sending Multipe Images Over a NetworkStream

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm having trouble sending multiple images over a `NetworkStream`. My code attempts to maintain a connection with the server as it waits for the command to send an image.

**Client Code:**

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(HOSTNAME, PORT);

while (true)
{
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // <-- Exception thrown here

    WaitCmd(stream, "deskcap"); // Waits until the command "deskcap" is received from the server

    Bitmap capture = CaptureDesktop();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    capture.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    byte[] imageBuffer = ms.GetBuffer();
    stream.Write(imageBuffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
private void desktopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpItem c = (TcpItem)clientsComboBox.SelectedItem;
    NetworkStream stream = c.client.GetStream();
    string cmd = "deskcap";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cmd);
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    img.Save(@"C:\Users\" + username + @"\Captures\capture" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

**Exception:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

### Update

I added the ability for the client to send the size of the image before the server attempts to receive it. Images are now coming through somewhat corrupted.

**Updated Client Code:**

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(HOSTNAME, PORT);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

while (true)
{
    WaitCmd(stream, "deskcap"); // Waits until the command "deskcap" is received from the server

    Bitmap capture = CaptureDesktop();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    capture.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] imageArr = ms.ToArray();

    byte[] sizeHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(imageArr.Length);
    stream.Write(sizeHeader, 0, sizeHeader.Length); // Should always write four bytes
    stream.Write(imageArr, 0, imageArr.Length);
}
stream.Close();
```

**Updated Server Code:**

```
private void desktopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpItem c = (TcpItem)clientsComboBox.SelectedItem;
    NetworkStream stream = c.client.GetStream();

    string cmd = "deskcap";
    byte[] cmdBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cmd);
    stream.Write(cmdBuffer, 0, cmdBuffer.Length);

    byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];
    stream.Read(sizeBuffer, 0, 4); // Read a four byte header that contains the size of the image
    uint size = BitConverter.ToUInt32(sizeBuffer, 0);

    byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[size];
    stream.Read(imageBuffer, 0, (int)size);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
    img.Save(@"C:\Users\" + username + @"\Captures\capture" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception? In the server or the client? And for which operation? You have tried to run in a debugger to catch the exception?

Comment: The exception is thrown in the client, will edit the question to show location

Comment: This is going to happen when the server disconnects without saying goodbye nicely.  Improve your program by calling GetStream() only once, move it out of the loop.  And add a "bye" command so the client knows to stop reading.  And beware that the Read() method can still fail if the server disconnects for any other reason.

Comment: Note: there is no need to _"add a "bye" command"_. The correct way to indicate the desire to close the connection is to call `Socket.Shutdown()`, passing `SocketShutdown.Send` to initiate the shutdown or `SocketShutdown.Both` to acknowledge the shutdown (after sending whatever data remains to be sent, of course).